# Can I have a column that contains two different data types (date and text) under one common data type (date)in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqldatatypes

I am new to PostgreSQL. In the table below, the `end_date` was a **date** data type that contained `9999-01-01` as a value. I replaced `9999-01-01` to "Never Ending" as the date didn't look good for representation purpose. I want to reconvert my end_time column to **date** data type from **text** without losing "Never Ending" text value.

I have following data:

```
event_id(int) event_name(varchar)  start_date(date)  end_date(varchar)     
    1              abc              2020-07-28        2020-07-29 
    2              efg              2020-08-01        2020-09-01
    3              xyz              2021-06-01        Never Ending
```

The desire output:

```
event_id(int) event_name(varchar)  start_date(date)   end_date(date)     
    1              abc              2020-07-28         2020-07-29 
    2              efg              2020-08-01         2020-09-01
    3              xyz              2021-06-01         Never Ending
```

The Query that converted data type --> date to text:

```
select event_id, event_name, start_date,
case 
    when end_date = '9999-01-01' then 'Never Ending' 
    else CAST (end_date AS text)
end as end_date
from event
```

Comment: Isn't this working already? Maybe you should add `date ` before `'9999-01-01'`, but I don't see any other problem.

Comment: Nope! the data type is text/varchar I want it as date

Comment: Ah, now I understand. But I'm afraid that this won't work. A column can only have a single type, as far as I know.

Comment: Can't it be converted to date data type?

Comment: Could you use a null value to indicate no end date?

Comment: There is a date `9999-01-01` the data is not null :)

Comment: You can use `infinity` to indicate no end date

Answer (score 1):

I would use nulls instead of converting everything to text, so:

```
select
  event_id
  , event_name
  , start_date
  , case when end_date = '9999-01-01' then null else end_date end as end_date
from event
```

Also, you don't need all those parentheses :)

Comment: Replacing it with nulls solved the problem partially :) I have to treat the nulls separately. Was avoding the same. As there might be a multiple tables joins to the query in the future it will be costly then.

Comment: Like @a_horse_with_no_name mentioned in a comment to another answer, you can use `infinity` instead of `null`. You don't have to treat this separately.